# How we can load php sdk library in our drupal 7 module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Can Any one please tell me how we can load php sdk library in our drupal 7 module???

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "php sdk library" (which SDK?), but I'll provide info on including libraries in general.

You'll probably want to create a dependency on the [Libraries API](https://drupal.org/project/libraries) module. This provides a way for you to easily access the library and define which version of the SDK you require.

The library you want to access would go in the `libraries` sub-folder. So for instance, if I wanted to use the "Foobar" SDK, I would put the files in `sites/all/libraries/foobar`.

Here are the docs for using the Libraries API:
https://drupal.org/node/1342238

> **Loading**
>
> To load the library from inside your module, simply do:

```
<?php
libraries_load($name);
?>
```

It's just that easy! So continuing my example above, all I would need to do is add `libraries_load('foobar')`.